# How to read the control id and title inside a span by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input text box inside a span . Can anyone help me how to read the input id

```
<SPAN class=span1><INPUT id=name class="textobx" title=name value=U maxLength=1 ></SPAN>
```

How will I read the id and title of the input . 
Please help me in finding this.

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with `asp.net`? Please show the code you are working with.

Comment: <SPAN class=span1><INPUT id=name class="textobx" title=name value=U maxLength=1 ></SPAN> This is my code please help

Comment: The input id is `name`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
$(function(){
var id = $('span input').attr('id');
var title= $('span input').attr('title');
});
```

Also, you need to include `jquery` library

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this,

```
var id=$('span input').attr('id');
var tit=$('span input').attr('title');
```

Which will retrieve the `id` and `title` of `input` tag inside the span.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/SpfV9/)